# fit model to multiple groupings or subsets and extract original factor columns for data frame output

Tags: r, apply

I want to fit models and pull out specific parameters split by grouping factors (fac1 and fac2 below) or subsets. My problem is that when sapply outputs the correct parameters, I'm stuck with a list where the elements are named as combinations. What I want to get is a data.frame where I have a column for each factor with the appropriate label. I want to do this in **base R**.

Notice, the answer needs to be **general** and not for the specific names used in this case. The answer shouldn't be hindered if factor names include 'periods.' I'm eventually making something to use with any data, so this answer needs to do so, and also with any number of factors. I am actually using a custom function on a much larger data set but this example represents my issue.

Following is reproducible code:

```
#create data
fac1 <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",10))
fac2 <- rep(c(rep("X", 5), rep("Y",5)),2)
x <- rep(1:5,4)
set.seed(1337)
y <- rep(seq(2, 10, 2), 4) * runif(20, .8, 1.2)

xy <- data.frame(x,y) #bind parameters for regression

factors <- list(fac1, fac2) #split by 2 factors

sapply(split(xy, factors), function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2]) 
#run regression by these 4 groups, pull out slope
```

The output is:

```
A.X.c$x  B.X.c$x  A.Y.c$x  B.Y.c$x 
1.861290 2.131431 1.590733 1.746169
```

What I want is:

```
fac1 fac2 slope
A    X    1.861290 
B    X    2.131431 
A    Y    1.590733 
B    Y    1.746169
```

The following code might be made to be more general to accomplish this, but I'm worried about cases where expand.grid makes all possible combinations but the user has missing combinations in their data, and also whether the order will stay the same. Does expand.grid use a similar method as however split subsets the data that determines the order of the returned values?

```
slopes <- sapply(split(xy, factors), function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2]) 

dataframeplz <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(unique(fac1), unique(fac2))) 

dataframeplz$slope <- slopes

dataframeplz
```

Here is the *plyr* solution if that helps. It's so easy but not base R. Anyone know where in Hadley's code this magic happens? Githubbers?

```
library("plyr")
neatdata <- data.frame(fac1,fac2,x,y)
ddply(neatdata, c("fac1", "fac2"), function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base R, `aggregate` is the user friendly function for such situations.

```
aggregate(cbind(slope=1:nrow(xy))~fac1+fac2,FUN=function(r) coef(lm(y~x,data=xy[r,]))[2])
```

```
  fac1 fac2    slope
1    A    X 1.861290
2    B    X 2.131431
3    A    Y 1.590733
4    B    Y 1.746169
```

This could also be done with `by` in a fashion a bit more similar to your original.

```
setNames(as.data.frame.table(
  by(xy,list(fac1,fac2),FUN=function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2])),
  c("fac1","fac2","slope"))
```

Comment: This is perfect. I couldn't figure out how to make `aggregate` take extra variables. Could you verbally explain your code? At first glance I don't understand the reason for the `nrow` and then the `[r,]` indexing.

I will try to 'apply' this to my real case.

Comment: Now I understand. We are using aggregate to split by the factor combinations and return the index of the rows for xy in each subset, which are then used by the function to fit the model to only those rows. Smart. One modification I've used so far is replacing `1:nrow(xy)` with `row.names(xy)` as I think this is more general for cases that the row index number may not be the same due to missing data.

Answer (score 1):

I used base R and I focused on your specific example. This process has limitations as it handles column names as strings and keeps the appropriate info you need.

```
#create data
fac1 <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",10))
fac2 <- rep(c(rep("X", 5), rep("Y",5)),2)
x <- rep(1:5,4)
set.seed(1337)
y <- rep(seq(2, 10, 2), 4) * runif(20, .8, 1.2)

xy <- data.frame(x,y) #bind parameters for regression

factors <- list(fac1, fac2) #split by 2 factors

dt_res = sapply(split(xy, factors), function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2]) #run regression by these 4 groups, pull out slope

dt_res

# A.X.c$x  B.X.c$x  A.Y.c$x  B.Y.c$x 
# 1.861290 2.131431 1.590733 1.746169


dt_res = data.frame(dt_res)
dt_res = data.frame(names=rownames(dt_res),   # save the names as a column
                    slope=dt_res$dt_res,
                    row.names = NULL)

dt_res$names = gsub(".c[$]x","",dt_res$names)  # delete the unecessary characters from names
dt_res$fac1 = substr(dt_res$names,1,1)       # pick first character
dt_res$fac2 = substr(dt_res$names,3,3)       # pick 3rd character
dt_res[,c("fac1","fac2","slope")]

#    fac1 fac2    slope
# 1    A    X 1.861290
# 2    B    X 2.131431
# 3    A    Y 1.590733
# 4    B    Y 1.746169
```

I've updated it to something more general:

```
  #create data
fac1 <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",10))
fac2 <- rep(c(rep("X", 5), rep("Y",5)),2)
x <- rep(1:5,4)
set.seed(1337)
y <- rep(seq(2, 10, 2), 4) * runif(20, .8, 1.2)

xy <- data.frame(x,y) #bind parameters for regression

factors <- list(fac1, fac2) #split by 2 factors

res = sapply(split(xy, factors), function(c) coef(lm(c$y~c$x))[2]) #run regression by these 4 groups, pull out slope

# split names by . (that will be the split symbol always)
    names = strsplit(names(split(xy, factors)), split ="[.]")

# create empty vectors to store names
fac1 = vector()
fac2 = vector()

for (i in 1:length(names)){

# iterate through the list of names and keep values from the corresponding position
  fac1 = c(fac1, names[[i]][1])
  fac2 = c(fac2, names[[i]][2])
}


data.frame(fac1,
           fac2,
           slope = res,
           row.names = NULL)
```

Comment: This generates the table from this specific data, but it is not general. I updated my question to point out I need generalized code for any factor names or number of factors.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. Unfortunately you might need to use some packages in order to have a more robust general process. See packages dplyr and broom. That's how I deal with those type of problems easily. Or, maybe there's a base R process than I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I realize those are the easy alternatives, but I'm trying to hold out for the moment as this is part of a simple package I'm trying to make and I'd rather not have dependencies. Thanks for your comments. I will post a more general solution that I came up with, but I'm not sure if it's truly general or if it will fail with missing data.

Comment: My concern with strsplit though is when a user already has a period in the factor name.

Comment: Not just a concern. It will definitely break! But you can have a process that checks that and replaces all periods with another symbol, as you need the period to be generated only by "split(xy, factors))".

Answer (score 1):

A. Webb's answer is more elegant, but this `lapply/arbitrary function/do.call/rbind` workflow has been my last resort for this kind of thing for years:

```
# Move the factors inside your data frame, so they'll be available after the split()
xy <- data.frame(x, y, fac1, fac2)

# Iterate over the split
reglist <- lapply(split(xy, factors), FUN = function(group) {

    # Get the current factor levels
    group_levels <- unique(group[c("fac1", "fac2")])

    # Mash it all into a data.frame
    data.frame(group_levels, slope = coef(lm(y ~ x, data = group))[2])

})

# Collapse the list into a data.frame
do.call("rbind", reglist)
```