# split dataframe into subsets based on character value

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I want to perform the same regression for 4 different socio-economic levels of the interviewed persons in the survey data.

for example:

```
educational_level (of subset 1) = ß0 + ß1*educational_level_father + ß2*race + ... +u 

educational_level (of subset 2)= ß0 + ß1*educational_level_father + ß2*race + ... +u
```

...and so on. How do I divide the `data.frame` based on the value of one specific variable (column) in it?

Comment: List of potential duplicates: [fit model to multiple groupings or subsets and extract original factor columns for data frame output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119184/fit-model-to-multiple-groupings-or-subsets-and-extract-original-factor-columns-f),  [Splitting data and fitting distributions efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328631/splitting-data-and-fitting-distributions-efficiently), [Fit a different model for each row of a list-columns data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404198/fit-a-different-model-for-each-row-of-a-list-columns-data-frame).

Comment: You should note that Stack Overflow (SO) is not a code-writing service, but a question and answer site. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

One approach involves looping over the unique values in your subsetting column. Take a look at `for` and `subset`:

```
> data("iris")  ## A data set
> unique_species <- unique(iris$Species)  ## Get the unique values of the subsetting column
> results <- list()  ## Set up a list to store the regressions you will run within the loop
> for (species in unique_species) {  ## Loop over each unique value
+     data_subset <- subset(iris, iris$Species == species)  ## Subset based on the desired value
+     results[[species]] <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
                               data=data_subset)  ## Run each regression
+ }
```

This will produce:

```
> results
$setosa

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    data = data_subset)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
      2.3519        0.6548        0.2376        0.2521  


$versicolor

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    data = data_subset)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
      1.8955        0.3869        0.9083       -0.6792  


$virginica

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
    data = data_subset)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
      0.6999        0.3303        0.9455       -0.1698
```

For just 4 levels, this should be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A base-R solution would be:

```
dat.list <- split(x=YourData, f = as.factor(YourData$YourCharacter)
summary(lm(educ ~ educ_father, data=dat.list[[1]]))
summary(lm(educ ~ educ_father, data=dat.list[[2]]))
summary(lm(educ ~ educ_father, data=dat.list[[3]]))
summary(lm(educ ~ educ_father, data=dat.list[[4]]))
```

or, you could just assign the regression outcome to a list with a little `for` loop.

If you're looking for more efficient solutions (i.e. you have big data) you should implement a `nest-map-unnest` workflow. My personal preference to achieve this would be to rely on `broom`, `purr`, and `dplyr` packages, part of [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/). You can inspect some code from [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html). Other solutions are of course possible.