# Splitting data and fitting distributions efficiently

Tags: r, subset, simulation, distribution, purrr

For a project I have received a large amount of confidential patient level data that I need to fit a distribution to so as to use it in a simulation model. I am using R.

The problem is that I need is to fit the distribution to get the shape/rate data for at least 288 separate distributions (at least 48 subsets of 6 variables). The process will vary slightly between variables (depending on how that variable is distributed) but I want to be able to set up a function or loop for each variable and generate the shape and rate data for each subset I define.

An example of this: I need to find length of stay data for subsets of patients. There are 48 subsets of patients. The way I have currently been doing this is by manually filtering the data and then extracting those to vectors, and then fitting the data to the vector using `fitdist`.

i.e. For a variable that is gamma distributed:

```
vector1 <- los_data %>%
filter(group == 1, setting == 1, diagnosis == 1)

fitdist(vector1, "gamma")
```

I am quite new to data science and data processing, and I know there must be a simpler way to do this than by hand! I'm assuming something to do with a matrix, but I am absolutely clueless about how best to proceed.

Comment: May be you need a group by approach `los_data %>% group_by(group, setting, diagnosis) %>% summarise(yourfunc(columns))`  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: [fitdist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fitdistrplus/versions/1.0-8/topics/fitdist) takes a numeric vector and your chain is outputting a data frame (list of equal length vectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common practice is to split the data using `split` and then apply the function of interest on that group. Let's assume here we have four columns, group, settings, diagnosis and stay.length. The first three have two levels.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(1:2, 64, TRUE),
  setting  = sample(1:2, 64, TRUE),
  diagnosis  = sample(1:2, 64, TRUE), 
  stay.length = sample(1:5, 64, TRUE)
)
> head(df)
    group setting diagnosis var
1     1       1         1   4
2     1       1         2   5
3     1       1         2   4
4     2       1         2   3
5     1       2         2   3
6     1       1         2   5
```

Perform `split` and you will get a splitted `List` :

```
dfl <- split(df$stay.length, list(df$group, df$setting, df$diagnosis))

> head(dfl)
$`1.1.1`
[1] 5 3 4 1 4 5 4 2 1

$`2.1.1`
[1] 5 4 5 4 3 1 5 3 1

$`1.2.1`
[1] 4 2 5 4 5 3 5 3

$`2.2.1`
[1] 2 1 4 3 5 4 4

$`1.1.2`
[1] 5 4 4 4 3 2 4 4 5 1 5 5

$`2.1.2`
[1] 5 4 4 5 3 2 4 5 1 2
```

Afterwards, we can use `lapply` to perform whatever function on each group in the list. For example we can apply `mean`

```
dflm <- lapply(dfl, mean)
> dflm
$`1.1.1`
[1] 3.222222

.
.
.
.

$`2.2.2`
[1] 2.8
```

In your case, you can apply `fitdist` or any other function.

```
dfl.fitdist <- lapply(dfl, function(x) fitdist(x, "gamma"))

> dfl
$`1.1.1`
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
  estimate Std. Error
shape  3.38170  2.2831073
rate   1.04056  0.7573495

.
.
.


$`2.2.2`
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
  estimate Std. Error
shape 4.868843  2.5184018
rate  1.549188  0.8441106
```

Comment: Thanks! This is going to be very helpful but I am getting an error when I try and use fitdist, it says "data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1".

I had a look into the code of fitdist and the error message is associated with the code:

if(!(is.vector(data) & is.numeric(data) & length(data)>1)) stop("data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1")

Comment: I added how can you use `lapply` with `fitdist` as a function. And it is working fine in the example. One possibility  for the issue you're facing is that after you're splitting, the length of the vector of your data is 1. Make sure that after you split, you have enough data to perform `fitdist`. you can use `lapply(dfl, length)` to find the length of your list

Answer (score 0):

OK, your example isn't quite reproducible here, but I think the answer you want will something like the following:

```
result <- los_data %>%
group_by(group, setting, diagnosis) %>%
do({
  fit <- fitdist(.$my_column, "gamma")
  data_frame(group=.$group[1], setting=.$setting[1], diagnosis=.$diagnosis[1], fit = list(fit))
}) %>%
ungroup()
```

This will give you a data frame of all the fits, with columns for group, setting, diagnosis as well as a list-column which contains the fits for each one.  Since it is a list column, you will need to use double brackets to extract individual fits.  Example:

```
# Get the fit in the first row
result$fit[[1]]
```